# Swift auto-sizing tableview cells doesn't work for the first cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, tableview

I'm using auto-sized tableview cells in a tableViewController. I've added the two lines below to viewDidLoad(), performed the correct auto-layouts, and changed the Lines attribute of the label with extended texts to 0.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

However, the cells are not auto-sized when the view first loaded. But if I scroll down or flip it to landscape view and flip back, the auto sizing works perfectly. So I added the code below to viewWillAppear function:

```
tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index:0), withRowAnimation: .None)
```

Now the auto-sizing works fine for all the cells except the first cell when the tableView first loaded. How can I fix the first cell? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I've used layoutIfNeeded in the custom cell's didMoveToSuperview method to get the layout correct at launch. When I added subviews in code, I didn't need that, but with storyboard created cells, I did. You might try this.